# compare current and next item, skip next item if condition is met

Tags: python

Given I have a nested list and I want to iterate to check if a condition is met(compare current and next item) until the last item, how can I do this, and if the condition returns true, how can I move the pointer to skip the next and continue with the other items i.e. skip i+1, continue with i+2 ?

```
list = [[1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 1], [4, 2], [5, 1], [5, 1]]
for i, j in enumerate(list):
    if j[i] == list[i+1]:  #compare current and next item, but this will fail for the last item
      #set j[i] = "1st duplicate" and list[i+1] = "2nd duplicate" 
      # move pointer to [i+2]

    else:
      set j[i] = "ok"


    >>>> [ ["ok"],["1st duplicate"], ["2nd duplicate"], ["ok"],["1st duplicate"], ["2nd duplicate"] ]
```

Comment: what do you want to do to the elements?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham change their values, for example if they are same set ´j[1] = "1st duplicate"´, and ´j[1+2]= "second duplicate"´ else, set to ´"no duplicate"´

Comment: add an example to you question of exactly what will change and to waht

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the second last element.

```
for i, j in enumerate(my_list[:-1])
```

On the last check will `j` will be the second last element and  `my_list[i+1]` will be the last.

If you want to check the subelements you need to use `my_list[i+1][1]` or `my_list[i+1][0]`
Also don't use `list` as a variable name, it shadows the builtin `list`.

This will match your required output.

```
for i, j in enumerate(my_list[:-1]):
    if j[1] == my_list[i+1][1]:
        my_list[i]=["1st duplicate"]
        my_list[i+1 ]= ["2nd duplicate"]
    elif my_list[i] not in [["1st duplicate"],["2nd duplicate"]]:
        my_list[i] = [ "ok"]
[['ok'], ['1st duplicate'], ['2nd duplicate'], ['ok'], ['1st duplicate'], ['2nd duplicate']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can zip the original list with a copy of the same list without the first element, like this

```
for first, second in zip(my_list, my_list[1:]):
    ...
```

You don't have to worry about the index at all.